# Delphi Listview move items up / down with buttons

Tags: delphi, listview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delphi: Shift-Up and Shift-Down in the Listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289005/delphi-shift-up-and-shift-down-in-the-listview)

Hi
I have a list view and I want to be able to move the selected item / items up and down the list using buttons but cannot figure out how to do this, Could someone give me an example

many thanks

Colin

Comment: I strongly recommend using the list view in virtual mode

Comment: @Andreas, simular question however the exaple does not cope with multiselected items.

Answer (score 6):

```
procedure Tfrprodetile.ExchangeItems(lv: TListView; const i, j: Integer);
var
  tempLI: TListItem;
begin
  lv.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    tempLI := TListItem.Create(lv.Items);
    tempLI.Assign(lv.Items.Item[i]);
    lv.Items.Item[i].Assign(lv.Items.Item[j]);
    lv.Items.Item[j].Assign(tempLI);
    tempLI.Free;
  finally
    lv.Items.EndUpdate
  end;
end;
```

and for use :

move down :

```
ExchangeItems(lst_detile,lst_detile.Selected.Index,lst_detile.Selected.Index+1);
```

move up :

```
ExchangeItems(lst_detile,lst_detile.Selected.Index,lst_detile.Selected.Index-1);
```

note that "lst_detile" is name of my listview

good day !